# Basic Haskell function types?

Tags: haskell

Super basic question - but I can't seem to get a clear answer. The below function won't compile:

```
randomfunc :: a -> a -> b
randomfunc e1 e2
   | e1 > 2 && e2 > 2       = "Both greater"
   | otherwise              = "Not both greater"

main = do
   let x = randomfunc 2 1
   putStrLn $ show x
```

I'm confused as to why this won't work. Both parameters are type 'a' (Ints) and the return parameter is type 'b' (String)?

Error:

```
"Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘[Char]’"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite. Your function signature indicates: ***for all*** types `a` and `b`, randomfunc will return something of type `b` if given two things of type `a`.

However,  `randomFunc` returns a `String` (`[Char]`). And since you compare `e1` with `2` each other, you cannot use **all** `a`'s, only those that can be used with `>`:

```
(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Note that `e1 > 2` also needs a way to create such an an `a` from `2`:

```
(> 2) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Bool
```

So either use a specific type, or make sure that you handle all those constraints correctly:

```
randomfunc :: Int -> Int -> String

randomFunc :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> String
```

Answer (score 2):

> Both parameters are type 'a' (Ints) and the return parameter is type 'b' (String)?

In a Haskell type signature, when you write names that begin with a lowercase letter such as `a`, the compiler implicitly adds `forall a.` to the beginning of the type.  So, this is what the compiler actually sees:

```
randomfunc :: forall a b. a -> a -> b
```

The type signature claims that your function will work for whatever ("for all") types `a` and `b` the caller throws at you.  But this is not true for your function, since it only works on `Int` and `String` respectively.

You need to make your type more specific:

```
randomfunc :: Int -> Int -> String
```

On the other hand, perhaps you intended to ask the compiler to fill out `a` and `b` for you automatically, rather than to claim that it will work for all `a` and `b`.  In that case, what you are really looking for is the [PartialTypeSignatures](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PartialTypeSignatures#named-wildcards) feature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

randomfunc :: _a -> _a -> _b
```